# Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0

Tags: java

I get this error when running my code:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Module11_13_RealWorldProblem.main(Module11_13_RealWorldProblem.java:194)

I am not sure how to fix it.  I have a text doc that it should read for the information, but its not running.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Scanner;

class User

{

private final String id;

private final String lstName;

private final String FstName;

private final String addressLine1;

String addressLine2;

private final String City;

private final String State;

private final long zip;

long zipPlus4;

private final double payAmount;

private final String payDate;

private final double payDue;

public User(String id,String lstName,String fstName,

String addressLine1,String addressLine2,String City,

String State,long zip,long zipPlus4,

String payDate,double payAmount,double payDue)

{

this.id=id;

this.lstName=lstName;

this.FstName=fstName;

this.addressLine1=addressLine1;

this.addressLine2=addressLine2;

this.City=City;

this.State=State;

this.zip=zip;

this.zipPlus4=zipPlus4;

this.payAmount=payAmount;

this.payDate=payDate;

this.payDue=payDue;

}

public void setAddLine2(String add){

this.addressLine2=add;}

public void setZipPlus4(long zip){

this.zipPlus4=zip;}

public long getZip()

{

return zip;

}

public double getPayAMount()

{

return payAmount;

}

public double getDueAMount()

{

return payDue;

}

public String getDate()

{

return payDate;

}

public String getaddressLine1()

{

return addressLine1;

}

public String getaddressLine2()

{

return addressLine2;

}

public String getCity()

{

return City;

}

public String getState()

{

return State;

}

public String getlstName()

{

return lstName;

}

public String getId()

{

return id;

}

public String getfstName()

{

return FstName;

}

public long getZipPlus4(){

return zipPlus4;}

}

public class Module11_13_RealWorldProblem {

public static void main(String[] args){

List<User> lst=new ArrayList<User>();


Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

File file = new File(args[0]);

if (!file.exists()) {

System.out.println(args[0] + " does not exist.");

return;

}

if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {

System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");

return;

}

try {

List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(args[0]));

for (String line : allLines) {

//System.out.println(line);

String[] str=line.split("\\^");

User user=new User(str[0],str[1],str[2],

str[3],"".equals(str[4])?"NoValue":str[4],str[5],str[6],

Long.valueOf(str[7]),"".equals(str[8])?Long.MAX_VALUE:Long.valueOf(str[8]),

str[9],Double.valueOf(str[10]),Double.valueOf(str[11]));

lst.add(user);

}

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

System.out.println("Do opertauiosn,");

System.out.println("Do you want to output the report to the screen ('S'), to a file ('F') or both ('B')");

String ch=in.nextLine();

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

for (User user : lst) {

sb.append(user.getId()+"^"+user.getlstName()+","+user.getfstName()+"^"+user.getaddressLine1()

+"^"+("NoValue".equals(user.getaddressLine2())?"":user.getaddressLine2())+"^"+user.getCity()+"^"+user.getState()+"^"+user.getZip()+"^"+(

Long.MAX_VALUE==user.getZipPlus4()?"":user.getZipPlus4())

+"^"+user.getPayAMount()+"^"+user.getPayAMount()+"^"+user.getDueAMount());

sb.append("\n");

}

if("S".equalsIgnoreCase(ch))

{

System.out.println(sb.toString());

}

else if("F".equalsIgnoreCase(ch))

{

System.out.println("Enter output file name with full path");

String outputFilename=in.nextLine();

log(sb.toString(),outputFilename);

System.out.println("File successfully written");

}

else if("B".equalsIgnoreCase(ch))

{

System.out.println(sb.toString());

System.out.println("Enter output file name with full path");

String outputFilename=in.nextLine();

log(sb.toString(),outputFilename);

System.out.println("File successfully written");

}

}

public static void log(String message,String fName){

try {

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fName, true), true);

out.write(message);

out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.print("There is something wrong in output file/file path..retry !");

}



}

}
```

When producing the report
Skip those fields that are not part of the report format
Rearrange those fields that are in a different order so they correspond to the report format
Add a prompt to the user "Do you want to output the report to the screen ('S'), to a file ('F') or both ('B')".
If the user enters 'S' your code should display the report to the screen as it currently does. 
Whether the user enters an uppercase or lowercase letter should not matter. For example 'S' or 's' should not matter. In both cases, the user should display the data as described above.
If the user enters "F" (or "f"), then the app should
Prompt the user for the desired file name (including the file path) 
Output the report to a file using the file name / path the user entered. This output should be in the exact same format as the report is-if sent to the screen except that it outputs the report to a file.
If the user enters "B" (or "b"), then the app should output the report to both the screen and output it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The Program expects a input from command line while running the program.

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
```

args being a empty array, throwing an indexOutOfBoundException.

Make sure while running the program you are passing the file name.

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue, but it also did not create any new errors.  If my file name is "XYZHospitalExampleData-1"  where and how would I enter it in the code?

Comment: java <classname> <filename>

Comment: or you can replace args[0] with the filename

Comment: So like this:    File file = new File(text\XYZHospitalExampleData-1);  ?

Comment: use double quotes and make sure the file exists at the path and remove args[0] from print statements also

Comment: I now get this in the console:   XYZHospitalExampleData-1 does not exist.

Comment: I created a text folder in the src and pasted my text doc there.  why dosen't it see it

Comment: print `file.getAbsolutePath()` just after creating file object and you can find where it is trying to find the file.. adjust file accordingly or create file at the same place

Comment: I'm new to this, so I'm not sure where to insert this code: "print file.getAbsolutePath()" ?  Sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: `File file = new File("file_path"); System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: I pasted it n there.  The error states "C:\Users\John\eclipse-workspace\Module11_13_RealWorldProblem\XYZHospitalExampleData-1
XYZHospitalExampleData-1 does not exist."  I added the text file to the specified location, and it still says it does not exist.  Could it be that I have it as a .txt file?